# How to pass an image to a subprocess in python

Tags: python, image-processing, subprocess

The program is trying to read an image and then trying to pass the image to one of the subprocess for further preprocessing. I am trying to pass the image using subprocess args parameter.

```
import subprocess
import base64

img =[]
img.append(base64.b64encode(open('test.jpg', "rb").read()))
output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'test1.py',img])
print "output",output
```

In the code the image is being passed to test1.py, In test1.py i am  manipulating the image and then trying to return it back to the main process.

The current implementation is giving an error :
    **The filename or extension is too long**

so how can i pass this image from the main process to the subprocess and also how can i send back the image back from the subprocess to the main process?

Comment: Since `test1.py` is a python script, why are you calling it with `subprocess`?  Why not import it and use it's functions directly?   (If it is not currently written so that its functions/classes can be used directly, then it should be rewritten.)

Comment: @john1024 Actually the problem is that we are using different versions of a library in both the files and therefore i am trying to create a subprocess.

Comment: You will be better off passing the image via some other means -- may be temporary files, over sockets, pipes rather than process arguments.

Comment: Is there no way to use a temporary file (on disk)? So the programs would access it without any translation of it into base64?

Comment: @kkk Can you modify `test1.py` so that it accepts the image on stdin which you can provide via subprocess.PIPE?

Answer (score 2):

I do it by using the `subprocess.Popen`：

This is my directory structure:

```
.
├── main.py
├── src.jpg
└── test1.py
```

In the following code, I change the size of the src.jpg and save it as a new file called `src.thumbnail`.

This is the `main.py`. In the `main.py` I open two files as input stream(the stream of the original picture) and output stream(the stream of the target picture).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess

def main():
    # args are python interpreter and python file
    args = ["/home/yundongx/.virtualenvs/read/bin/python", "/tmp/img/test1.py"]
    with open("src.thumbnail", "w+b") as outstream, \
                        open("src.jpg", "rb") as instream:
        ps = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=instream, stdout=outstream)
        ps.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the `test1.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image
import sys
import io

size = (128, 128)

def main():
    try:
        im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(sys.stdin.buffer.read()))
        im.thumbnail(size)
        output = io.BytesIO()
        im.save(output, "JPEG")
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(output.getvalue())
    except IOError as e:
        sys.stderr.write("Cannot read the data\n")
        raise e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the `test1.py`, The program read the img data from the stdin(you need to convert it to the BytesIO), write the img data(Saved into the BytesIO) to the stdout after processing it.